# IntelliJ Lombok - src/integration-test classes don't see generated lombok code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 + lombok plugin with the following structure:

[image]

Edit: this is the Module Content Root configuration:

[image]

Everything works as expected in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`, but classes in `src/integration-test` and `src/end-to-end-test` don't see the generated lombok code (so no autocomplete).

I can still run the tests without any issue though.

Does anyone have any idea what I should do to benefit from auto-complete from these other test source folders?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a lombok plugin first in intellij and then in settings you need to enable it. It doesnt not work in the way in which it works in eclipse.

Comment: Indeed, the plugin is installed and activated (it works for `src/main` and `src/test`)

Comment: I updated IntelliJ to 2018.1 (as well as the lombok plugin version) and now it works

Comment: Done..Awesome..Great..!

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable Annotation processing for your modules in IntelliJ. If you have enabled it already make sure integration-test and end-to-end-test are listed under Default.

Go to settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)
->Build Execution Deployment
-->Compiler
--->Annotation processors

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I can't test it anymore - as mentioned in the comments, I updated IntelliJ to 2018.1 (as well as the lombok plugin) and now it works fine

Comment: and make sure the checkbox "Enable annotation processing" is actually ticked for Default

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you have enabled Lombok itself in project properties as far as processing annotations on that. Everything is in Project preferences.

Comment: Lombok is working on src/main and src/test (methods are generated and autocomplete is working), so I guess this means it's enabled at the project level?

Comment: Yes, it's on the project level but your test folders have to be added in the root content. Go to Module Settings -> Modules and take a look into right panel Content Root

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my content root - things look the same for the new folders as for the test one

Comment: Sebastien, yeah. it looks ok. Only thing I can suggest is to restart IDE and/or rebuild the project from terminal with maven/gradle. It helped me sometimes

Comment: Unfortunately I did both, but to no avail. I had a look at the xml conf files generated by IntelliJ, but without much success either